# Python Pandas - Trouble Zipping Together 2 DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble using the zip() function to zip two dataframe columns together but I think I am somehow messing up retrieving the columns. It is my understanding that retrieving the columns should be as simple as `df[['column']]` but is it be different in this case for some reason?

Instructions:

Using `zip()`, zip together the `'Total Population'` and `'Urban population (% of total)'` columns of `df_pop_ceb`. Assign the resulting zip object to pops.

My Attempt:

```
# Initialize reader object: urb_pop_reader
urb_pop_reader = pd.read_csv('ind_pop_data.csv', chunksize = 1000)

# Get the first DataFrame chunk: df_urb_pop
df_urb_pop = next(urb_pop_reader)

# Check out the head of the DataFrame
print(df_urb_pop.head())

# Check out specific country: df_pop_ceb
df_pop_ceb = df_urb_pop[df_urb_pop['CountryCode' == 'CEB']

# Zip DataFrame columns of interest: pops
pops = zip(df_pop_ceb[['Total Population']],df_pop_ceb[['Urban population (% of total)']])

# Turn zip object into list: pops_list
pops_list = list(pops)

# Print pops_list
print(pops_list)
```

Error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 14
  pops = zip(df_pop_ceb[['Total Population']],df_pop_ceb[['Urban population (% of total)']])
   ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo, need `]`:

```
#                                      missing  ]      
df_pop_ceb = df_urb_pop[df_urb_pop['CountryCode'] == 'CEB']
```

Then for zip 2 columns need only one `[]` for `Series` if need `list` of `tuples` of values in columns, because double `[]` return one column `df` here:

```
pops = zip(df_pop_ceb['Total Population'],df_pop_ceb['Urban population (% of total)'])
```

else get columns names:

```
pops = zip(df_pop_ceb[['Total Population']],df_pop_ceb[['Urban population (% of total)']])
print (list(pops))
[('Total Population', 'Urban population (% of total)')]
```

Sample:

```
df_pop_ceb = pd.DataFrame({'Total Population':[1,2,3,4,5,9],
                           'Urban population (% of total)':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})
print (df_pop_ceb)
   Total Population  Urban population (% of total)
0                 1                              5
1                 2                              3
2                 3                              6
3                 4                              9
4                 5                              2
5                 9                              4

pops = zip(df_pop_ceb[['Total Population']],df_pop_ceb[['Urban population (% of total)']])
print (list(pops))
[('Total Population', 'Urban population (% of total)')]

pops = zip(df_pop_ceb['Total Population'],df_pop_ceb['Urban population (% of total)'])
print (list(pops))
[(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 9), (5, 2), (9, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know where I got the double [ ] from or if I'll ever consistently remember dataframe related notations.

Comment: doble `[]` is used for subset, e.g. if need seelct multiple columns like `df_pop_ceb[['Total Population','Urban population (% of total)']])`